# Is there a way to view relations within a project?

Tags: rider

My end goal is to view dependencies across my code base so that I can better manage the architecture of my Unity project. My initial thought was to use the Project Diagram feature introduced in Rider 2020.3, but as the name suggests I think this feature is only for viewing relationships between projects. Is there a built-in way for Rider to display a diagram with the relationships between all of my classes within a project?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should wait for [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-4321) to be implemented in Rider to achieve your goal. Right now, it is not possible.